# linear-gradient inaccurate in Google Chrome

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a little problem in Google Chrome with my gradient:

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(43,66,88,0) 144px,#f4f7fa 144px), radial-gradient(at top center, #44698b,#162a3c);
}

.header {
    height: 144px;
}

.main {
    height: 500px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Live view: http://jsfiddle.net/p726s/

You can see the problem in the picture:

[image]

[image]

Even if there is set the gradient to end at `144px` and the next color begins at the exact same pixel, Chrome creates a little gradient so that the first color does not end at `144px` but at `142px`. The next two pixels it creates a gradient to the second color instead of creating a straight line. I don't know how do force the browser to don't do it. Has anyone any suggestion?

**Edit 6th July 2016:**

It seems that Google has fixed that problem the last months…

Comment: my eyes can't distinguish the 2 pictures you posted. I also tested your fiddle in the latest version of Chrome, it seems to look OK. BTW Chrome has the best support for the newest features of CSS, FF is the worst, you don't need to support FF much because I think that browser may be faded out soon.

Comment: Could you try to clarify what the problem is?  From what I can see everything looks fine.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it isn't clear and it's likely to be closed as 'not clear' by a moderator if they see it.

Comment: I added a second zoomed picture and edited the description. Firefox is still a major used browser – especially in Germany where the design is used mainly. So I think to say you don't have to support it is a joke, it still is nearly as often used as Chrome. And besides this, the problem does not occur in Firefox. Chrome is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this issue with my own Chrome installation; is your Google Chrome updated to the latest version (33.0.1750.154m)?

I realise that some people on your site may not have (or be willing) to update their Chrome installation (e.g. they have Google Update turned off), however Chrome is known to be picky with some stuff, and you might have just stumbled into one of the things that it just doesn't like.

Also, please rephrase your question; I could only *just* about see the difference in your gradients and some people (like King King, whom replied to your OP) may not be able to see the difference.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of chrome. I simply cannot believe that a browser can't even create the easiest form of a gradient…

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Chrome is triggering subpixel rendering. Check if is there any CSS 2D or 3D transformation activated on the element or parent container, such as `transform:rotate()`, and disable it to test.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't.

Comment: Sorry for the long time to reply. If you change the gradient background to a plain color or to an image, the problem go away?

Comment: Yes, it does and this is how I use it at the moment… with an image.